# HOW TO Configure url and view for filter between two dates

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I don't know to how configure `views.py` and `urls.py` in myapp. for filter a list between dates from an input date in a template.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
   tipo_doc = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_doc)
   num_doc = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
   ...

class Consulta (models.Model):
   numero = models.ForeignKey(Paciente)
   fecha = models.DateField()
   ...
```

This is my file "lista.html" in templates:

```html
<h5>
  Fecha desde: <input class="inputDate" id="fechadesde" value={{ fecha_d }} />
  Fecha hasta: <input class="inputDate" id="fechahasta" value={{ fecha_h }} />
  <a href="/clinica/filtrar_consulta" class="button">Filtrar</a>
</h5>

<ul class="actions">
 ...
```

I need to filter the list by `paciente` and between 2 dates (`fecha_d`, `fecha_h`), but I don't know how to pass parameters in url. Thank You

Comment: 1) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/  
2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd use a form to do the filtering:

lista.html:

```
<form method='get' action='.'>
    Fecha desde: <input class="inputDate" name='fechadesde' />
    Fecha hasta: <input class="inputDate" name="fechahasta" />
    <input type='submit' value='Filtrar'/>
</form>
```

Then, in your view, you need to retrieve these values and filter the queryset based on that.
This is a code fragment that could be used either in a function or class based view:

```
qs = Paciente.objects.all()
fecha_desde = request.GET.get('fechadesde', None)
fecha_hasta = request.GET.get('fechahasta', None)
if fecha_desde:
    qs = qs.filter(fecha__gte=fecha_desde)
if fecha_hasta:
    qs = qs.filter(fecha__lte=fecha_hasta)
context = {'consultas': qs}
```

And go from there. A good enhancement would be to use django form system instead of manually writting your html and performing manual validation

Read more about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: Hi, I did what you say, but "request.GET.get" return value always is None

Comment: Are you sure you added the "name" attribute to the inputs?

Comment: this is my html:   <label for="fecha_desde">Fecha desde: </label>
    <input id="fecha_desde" type="text" name="fecha_desde" value="{{ fecha_desde }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="fecha_hasta">Fecha hasta: </label>
    <input id="fecha_hasta" type="text" name="fecha_hasta" value="{{ fecha_hasta }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;  
    <label for="num_paciente">Nº HC: </label>
     <input id="num_paciente" type="text" name="num_paciente" value="{{ num_paciente }}">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="{% url "consultas_lista"%}" class="button">Filtrar</a>

Comment: Alvaro, sos de Rosario y yo tratando de escribir en INGLES JAJA

Comment: jajaja terrible...! fijate que el name dice "fecha_desde",entonces en request.GET.get() usa el mismo nombre 'fecha_desde'

Comment: Si ahi no te sale, revisa el valor que tiene request.GET.. pero deberia funcionar bien si el form tiene method="get"

Comment: este es el views.py: ` ....fecha_desde =  request.GET.get('fecha_desde')
 fecha_hasta =  request.GET.get('fecha_hasta')
 numero1 = request.GET.get('num_paciente')
 consultas = Consulta.objects.all()
 consultas = consultas.filter(numero=numero1) data['object_list'] = consultas
 return render(request, template_name,data)`

Comment: Quiero que aunque sea me filtre por num_paciente(la variable se llama numero1) pero tampoco anda, lo de las fechas lo veo despues

Comment: Mandame el archivo de views y el html al mail si tenes un segundo, asi lo veo bien... alvarotuso@hotmail.com